# Spark Scala nested JSON stored as structure table

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have huge no of nested JSON having more than 200 keys want to convert & store in structure table.

```
  |-- ip_address: string (nullable = true)
  |-- xs_latitude: double (nullable = true)
  |-- Applications: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |-- b_als_o_isehp: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- b_als_p_isehp: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- b_als_s_isehp: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- l_als_o_eventid: string (nullable = true)
                 ....
```

Read JSON and get each `ip_address` having one application array data

```
 {"ip_address": 1512199720,"Applications": [{"s_pd": -1,"s_path": "NA", "p_pd": "temp0"}, {"s_pd": -1,"s_path": "root/hdfs", "p_pd": "temp1"},{"s_pd": -1,"s_path": "root/hdfs", "p_pd": "temp2"}],}

val data = spark.read.json("file:///root/users/data/s_json.json")
 var appDf = data.withColumn("data",explode($"Applications")).select($"Applications.s_pd", $"Applications.s_path", $"Applications.p_pd", $"ip_address")
 appDf.printSchema
/// gives 
root
  |-- s_pd: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |-- s_path: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |-- p_pd: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |-- ip_address: string (nullable = true)
```

In each dataframe record contain an array with duplicate records. How to get the record in table format.
 [image]

Comment: on top of my head you can try `appDf.select("ip_addres", "xs_latitude", "Applications.*")` to flatten out such a structure. or is it arbitrarily deeply nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mistake

Your mistake is that *you are using the original (`Application`) struct column to select the nested struct in separate column*.

## Solution

You had to *select from the exploded column which is `data`*

```
var appDf = data.withColumn("data",explode($"Applications"))
  .select($"ip_address", $"data.s_pd", $"data.s_path", $"data.p_pd")
```

and you should get

```
+----------+----+---------+-----+
|ip_address|s_pd|s_path   |p_pd |
+----------+----+---------+-----+
|1512199720|-1  |NA       |temp0|
|1512199720|-1  |root/hdfs|temp1|
|1512199720|-1  |root/hdfs|temp2|
+----------+----+---------+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful